# custom pages and page templates wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

im using wordpress as a CMS for my personal portfolio website.  i want to be able to create different pages that have slightly different variations of the header etc.

after looking around i realised that i can use pages.php and template pages however i do not understand how they work.

for instance currently i made a contact page via creating a new page on the dashboard and doing the html there. i took the permalink and put it inside an 'a' tag that sits in my header. this then goes to that page fine but i want my header to be different.

i guess basically i am confused because the instructions i have looked at do not explain how the page is displayed.
in a page template do i do this?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: [your page name here]
*/
?>
<?php include(“header_new.php”); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but what confuses me is how does wordpress know were to put the page?? obviouslly for the index you do a post loop. but all i want is my page to be displayed.

am i missing something like this?...

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: [your page name here]
*/
?>
<?php include(“header_new.php”); ?>
// POST PAGE FUNCTION HERE>>>>????
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

my current theme can be viewed here

hope this is not something obvious that i have missed. many thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First take a look at this page template (only an example)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header('contact'); ?>

    <div id="post-wrap" class="full-width-wrap">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>           
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you save above code in a file and name it `page-contactpage.php` and keep/save it inside your theme's root folder (where index.php is) then it'll be one of your template and you can select this template from `template` combo box (located at the right side in the page attribute meta box) when you are creating a new page from `admin->Add New Page`. If you create a page with this template then your page will use this template instead of the default page template.

Notice the line `get_header('contact');` that is a different header I've used instead of the `header.php` and that header have to be available with name `header-contact.php` (may be with different content) in the same folder. Now your contact page will use this template with a different header if you select this template when creating it.

Comment: many thanks! so although its using a post loop it will only get my contact page if thats the only page using this template? Best